# ReactJS :Syntax error: src/App.js: Unexpected token (16:6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting started with reactjs and tried a simple example in a tutorial.Syntax error occurs when returning html tags.

Here is the error I'm getting

> ./src/App.js
> Syntax error: C:/Users/react-tutotial/src/App.js: Unexpected token (16:6)

```
14 |   render() {
   |     return{
16 |       <div>
   |       ^
17 |         <button>Increment</button>
18 |         {this.state.count}
```

This is the `app.js` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      count : 0
    };
  }
  render() {
    return{
      <div>
        <button>Increment</button>
        {this.state.count} 
      </div>
    };
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The `{...}` in `return { ... }` denote an **object literal**. An object literal needs to contain a sequence of `key: value,` pairs, not JSX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `(`/`)` there, not `{`/`}`:

```
 render() {
    return (                                 // changed this line
      <div>
        <button>Increment</button>
        {this.state.count} 
      </div>
    );                                       // changed this line
  }
```

And know that `()`s there are optional, but if you do remove them, `<div>` must be in the same line as `return`, like `return <div>` an on. (When you break a line after `return` JavaScript goes nuts.)

---

**Edit:**

Ok, I feel like I should elaborate on what "goes nuts" is: when you break a line right after `return`, JavaScript will basically consider it a `return;` and ignore the rest. And that is effectively the same as `return undefined;`. Blame this on [JavaScript's ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Automatic_semicolon_insertion) "feature".

About why exactly `{`/`}` doesn't work: Although when **inside** a JSX "expression" [you can use curly braces to place any JavaScript expression](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx), at that point where the error appears, you are not *inside* a JSX expression yet. This makes that code be interpreted as regular JavaScript expression. And in regular JavaScript, a curly brace alone either creates a context (where `let` variables would be local, for instance) or object literals. A return expects an expression. A context is not an expression. And your code is not (nor it should be) a valid object literal.